# How to parse Json object in swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3

Hi my question is related to json object. i have this link "http://ip-api.com/json" and this link gives the details of your IP Address. i only need to print IP Address from this json file in swift 3. i am very new might be my question is basic but i need some help to sort out my project. so for i have done like below.

```
let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://ip-api.com/json")!

    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL as URL)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

        if (statusCode == 200) {
            print("Everyone is fine, file downloaded successfully.")

            do{

                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [String:AnyObject]

                if let stations = json["city"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {



                  for station in stations {

                      if let name = station["regionName"] as? String {

                        self.names.append(name)
                        print("this is query\(name)")

                      }
                      else{
                         print ("no ip address is found")
                    }

                  }

                }

            }
            catch {
                print("Error with Json: \(error)")
            }

        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP address is the value for key `query` on the top level of the JSON

```
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
if let query = json["query"] as? String {
  print(query)
}
```

In Swift 3 the type of a JSON dictionary is `[String:Any]`

PS: You don't need a URL request for this task, pass the URL directly and use the native structs `URL` (and `URLRequest`)

```
let requestURL = URL(string: "http://ip-api.com/json")!
...
let task = session.dataTask(with: requestURL) {
```

Comment: i am using an api for this project and is not free. is there any other way you know to get the ip address from iOS Device. ??? thanks

Comment: For example [wtfismyip - IPv4](https://ipv4.wtfismyip.com/json) and [wtfismyip - IPv6](https://wtfismyip.com/json)