# How to Parse JSON data string individually in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I'm a newbie to JSON. I've done a few readings but I'm still confused and I'm getting errors.

How do you parse the following data?

```
[{"symbol":"ALI","date":"1/22/2018","open":44.9000,"high":45.5000,"low":44.9000,"close":45.2000,"bid":45.1500,"ask":45.2000,"volume":6698800,"value":303245610.0000,"netForeign":-42279365.0000}]
```

I would like to get each string individually.

For instance: Symbol, Date, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

As a reference, I tried the following solution but got an error:
[How to parse Json object in swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378048/how-to-parse-json-object-in-swift-3)

Comment: where your code that you tried?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no efforts were shown to solve the problem

Comment: Why? Vadian has answered my question. Kindly read.

Comment: thats not what i stated as the reason.

Comment: You just stated "because no efforts were shown to solve the problem". My problem was solved by Vadian.

Comment: that means **`YOU`** didnt showed any efforts, there was no code added that showed you tried something, although it was nice of @vadian to still answer.

Comment: I did. I just added one of the codes I tried to use. Furthermore, I explained my problem in the simplest term I can so my question will be much clearer

Comment: **`:D`** are you serious, are you referring to the JSON as **`code`** that you had to read.

Comment: Fine, do what you want. Haha. As I stated, I am a newbie with JSON :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Swift 4 it's very straightforward with the `Decodable` protocol:

```
let jsonString = """
[{"symbol":"ALI","date":"1/22/2018","open":44.9000,"high":45.5000,"low":44.9000,"close":45.2000,"bid":45.1500,"ask":45.2000,"volume":6698800,"value":303245610.0000,"netForeign":-42279365.0000}]
"""

struct Item : Decodable {
    let symbol, date : String
    let open, high, low, close, bid, ask, value, netForeign : Double
    let volume : Int
}

do {
    let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print("error: ", error)
}
```

Or even with decoding the date string as `Date`

```
struct Item : Decodable {
    let symbol : String
    let date : Date
    let open, high, low, close, bid, ask, value, netForeign : Double
    let volume : Int
}

do {
    let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)
    let result = try decoder.decode([Item].self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch {
    print("error: ", error)
}
```

---

This is an example to put `JSONDecoder` and `URLSession` together:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://api.whatever...")!
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url) { (data, _, error) in
  if error != nil {
     print(error!)
  } else {
     do {
        let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: data!)
        print(result)
    } catch {
        print("error: ", error)
    }
  }

}.resume()
```

Please learn to **read** JSON. It's pretty simple. There are only two collection types (array, dictionary) and four value types (string, number, bool and null). See also my answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423367/correctly-parsing-json-in-swift-3/39423764#39423764):

Comment: Hi Vadian, thanks for the help! Sorry but I think I haven't made my question clear, but I am actually fetching the son file from the internet...

Comment: Use `URLSession` to get the data. There are hundreds of examples here on SO for example in the linked question. In this case omit the line `let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)` and use the `data` returned from the `dataTask`

Comment: Hi Vadian, I tried using the solution on the link you provided but I got the ff. error: Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' to 'NSDictionary'.

Comment: Do not use `JSONSerialization`. Pass the `data` to `JSONDecoder` in this answer.

Comment: Regarding your previous answer just now, how do I use the data returned from the dataTask? Sorry newbie here. I got the part `let urlString = https://api.forecast.io/forecast/apiKey/37.5673776,122.048951
  
  let url = URL(string: urlString)
  URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!) { (data, response, error) in
   if error != nil {
    print(error)
   } else {` on my code, however, how do I put the value of the dataTask inside the `do {
   let data=`?

Comment: Wow, I tried it and it works great! However, how do I "get" each data individually? For instance, I only want to get the "Symbol" item, is that possible?

Comment: In terms of JSON, an *object* or *item* is everything between `{  }`. Your JSON is an array `[]` of items containing values for `symbol`, `date` etc.. To get only the `symbol` value declare only the line `let symbol : String` in the struct. If you mean to get the values individually use a loop: `for item in result { print(item.symbol, item.date) }`

Comment: Hi Vadian, I greatly appreciate you helping me. I tried doing it and I got the ff. printed: `[MyApp.ViewController.Symbol(symbol: "ALI")` around eight times... I only need to have the word ALI printed. I hope that's possible... Thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Have you tried the `for` loop?

Comment: Hi Vadian, sorry my bad. I commented before you fully answered my question. I got it, I used the code and I got the word "ALI" eight times because there are eight items on the JSON file. I got it now. Thank you very much, you're a real genius! :)